# mysql join three tables order by third

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query

```
   SELECT jss_products.* from jss_products_tree,jss_products 
   WHERE stock!=0 AND
   jss_products.productID = jss_products_tree.productID 
   and sectionID=1 order by price
```

Which returns me a big array with products. Now I need to join 3rd table jss_extrafields_values,
which has productID and content fields, and somehow order the array by the content from 3rd table. Also it might have more than one rows with different content but same product.ID.. any ideas on how to join all of them? I tried a lot of tutorials but none of them helped me.. thanks

Comment: You should provide us with the structure of your tables

Comment: you are doing it wrong. please read about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax

Comment: Its not wrong, it is better to read tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easier to use join over from table1, table2 as its better to read. And you can just join the 3th table.

```
SELECT jss_products.* from jss_products_tree
INNER JOIN jss_products 
  ON jss_products.productID = jss_products_tree.productID 
INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_values
  on jss_extrafields_values.productId = jss_products.productID
WHERE stock!=0 AND   
and sectionID=1 
order by jss_extrafields_values.field
```